# How do I get JavaScript code in another directory into current JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I get another JavaScript file in pure JavaScript? Assume that the main.js below is at the directory "./resources" and data.js is at the directory "./resources/data".

./resources/main.js:

```
var array = /*Missing Code*/;
```

./resources/data/data.js:

```
var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, "etc."];
```

How does this work in **pure** JavaScript?

Comment: Are you in a web browser or in Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to *export* the array:

```
export var x = [1, 2, 3, 4, "etc."]
```

Now that you have exported that value, you can *import* it from `main.js` like this:

```
var data = require('./data/data.js')
var array = data.x
```

Of course, it's not strictly necessary to give the module import a separate name (though it is an accepted practice):

```
var array = require('./data/data.js').x
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work. If what you want to import is an array I'd suggest you to create a json file.

```
let array = require('./misingCode.json');
```